# system("pause") won't work with freopen

Tags: c++, console, system, console-application, freopen

See below in comment.

```
int main(){
    //freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);//if I uncomment this line the console will appear and disappear immediately
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<x<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: More importantly, *why are you using `system("pause")`*?

Comment: I'm using this function because I want see the program output.

Comment: Read this: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html and/or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 1: use `cin.ignore` instead of `system`:

```
...
cout<<x<<endl;
cin.ignore(1, '\n'); // eats the enter key pressed after the number input
cin.ignore(1, '\n'); // now waits for another enter key
...
```

Solution 2: if you are using MS Visual Studio, press Ctrl+F5

Solution 3: reopen `con` (will only work on Windows, seems your case)

```
...
cout<<x<<endl;
freopen("con","r",stdin);
system("pause");
...
```

If you use solution 3, don't forget to add comments on what the code is doing and why :)

Comment: The solution 3 is works very well! Thanks! My program reads the input.txt file for the numbers and generates some data. This is for studing.

Comment: hehe, this is a repugnant kludge, but it has *style*

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::ifstream` instead of redirecting stdin:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
    if (fin)
    {
        fin >> x;
        std::cout  << x << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open input file!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.ignore(1, '\n'); // waits the user to hit the enter key
}
```

(Borrowed the `cin.ignore` trick from anatolyg's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You use `freopen` to change your program's standard input. Any program you start inherits your program's standard input, including the `pause` program. The `pause` program reads some input from *input.txt* and terminates.

Comment: I need to run the program by double-clicking, and outputs the data to the console.But my program immediately disappear after output data.